# riotjs route not working in requirejs

Tags: requirejs, amd, riot.js

how can I use riot route with requirejs?
I know it has a js file for AMD that start with `define` but I can not use this in my project

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: '/static/front/js',
paths: {
    jquery: [
        'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min',
        'lib/jquery-3.2.1.min'
    ],
    hammerjs: 'lib/hammerjs',
    velocity: 'lib/materialize/velocity.min',
    materialize: 'lib/materialize/materialize',
    riot: 'lib/riot/riot',
    route: 'lib/riot/route',
},
shim: {
    'materialize': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'hammerjs', 'velocity']
    },
    'riot': {
        deps: ['materialize', 'route']
    }
}
});
define([
'riot',
'route'
], function (riot, route) {
'use strict';
require(['view/all'], function () {
    route.base("/"); // start router
    route.start(true);

    route('/..', function () {
        alert('It Work!');
    });
});
});
```

in `require(['view/all'], function ()...` I compile my tags by `riot -w ./ ./all.js` and edit that:

all.js:

```
define(['riot'], function (riot) {'use strict';
riot.tag2('component', '<h2>test</h2>', '', '', function(opts) {
    this.on('mount', function(){
        $('h2').html("change")
    })
});
riot.tag2('mytag', '<h1>mytag</h1>', '', '', function(opts) {
});
});
```

and it work well, because when I call `riot.mount('mytag')` it works

Comment: may i ask why do you use requiresjs for your modules?

Comment: because i have same problem with webpack

Comment: Could you check if with jquery 3.2.1 the route works fine?. I have problem with inicialization of route with that jquery version.